# Clone a specific branch from Google Cloud

Tags: git, google-cloud-datastore

How do I clone a specific branch from Google Cloud?

```
gcloud source repos clone default -b mybranch --project=projectname
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this.  My branch is called elm.

```
PS C:\Users\Jeffrey Rennie\gitrepos> gcloud source repos clone quokka
Cloning into 'C:\Users\Jeffrey Rennie\gitrepos\quokka'...
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

Project [bookshelf-dotnet] repository [quokka] was cloned to [C:\Users\Jeffrey Rennie\gitrepos\quokka].
PS C:\Users\Jeffrey Rennie\gitrepos> cd quokka
PS C:\Users\Jeffrey Rennie\gitrepos\quokka> git checkout -t origin/elm
Branch elm set up to track remote branch elm from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'elm'
PS C:\Users\Jeffrey Rennie\gitrepos\quokka>
```